# .htaccess mod_rewrite RewriteRule for categories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to have http://www.mywebsite.com/cd2012/legal rather than http://www.mywebsite.com/cd2012/index.php?legal=1

i have tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule guarantees/(.*) cd2012/index\.php/legal=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule guarantees cd2012/index\.php/legal=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^guarantees/$ cd2012/index\.php/legal=$1 [R=301,L]
```

none of them working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite, you don't want to use `[R=301,L]` as this basically means "tell the users browser that this document is permanently moved to this location"

You also shouldn't escape the final path, as it's not regex.

Instead, do this (according to your example):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cd2012/?$ cd2012/index.php
RewriteRule ^cd2012/(.*) cd2012/index.php?$1=1
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it still isn't working. i tried this RewriteRule ^cd2012/(.*)/(.*)$ cd2012/index.php?$1=$2
still no hope. it redirect to 404.

Comment: @Mr.Crowley Are you sure that `cd2012/index.php` exists?

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?$1=1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Right now this is what does the magic for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cd2012/legal$ cd2012/index.php?legal=1 [L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. it still shows the original URL without any changes.

Comment: htaccess does not change your urls in your pages for you, it redirect them, if you are typing `cd2012/index.php?legal=1`, it is normal that it stays as it is, the rule I gave you is for : if someone type `cd2012/legal` in the browser, the request in the server will be redirected instead to `cd2012/index.php?legal=1`. IF you want to reidrect people that type `cd2012/index.php?legal=1` in their browser to `cd2012/legal` then that something else (you will need to do a 301 or 302 redirection)

Comment: i used RedirectMatch 301 ^/legal  http://www.mysite.com/cd2012/index.php?legal=1 and if user writes /legal then it will redirect them into the page they requested, now i want to clean the url's like i wrote,  http://www.mywebsite.com/cd2012/index.php?legal=1 into http://www.mywebsite.com/cd2012/legal.

Comment: you need to go through your pages and change all the url, htacces does not do that for you

Comment: i know tomcat does it, url rewriting i mean. Are you sure apache doesn't ?

Comment: url rewriting is a thing, changing the links in your pages is another thing